# How to prove that there is a continuous surjection from Cantor space onto a closed subspace?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

Let C be the Cantor space and let Y be a non-empty closed subspace of C. How do I go about showing that there exists a continuous surjection from C onto Y?

This is from a topology course, any hints/guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a big theorem, namely that every compact metric space is a continuous image of the Cantor set. It is proved in many topology (or analysis) books, for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space) gives Willard's General topology book, section 30.7. I also found it in Real Analysis notes by Saeed Zakeri 
presently [available online](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~zakeri/mat701/701notes.pdf), see Theorem 2.77 (p.59) there. The proof uses "dyadic filtrations" which kind of mimic the construction of the Cantor set. Applications of this "universal surjectivity" are discussed in a [paper by Yoav Benyamini](https://www.um.es/functanalysis/meetingsold/Zafra/III_Escuela_AF_files/cantorset2.pdf) (it refers to the topology books by Engelking, and by Hocking and Young, and I think I first read this proof from Dugundji's Topology book). Another proof, via the Hilbert cube is outlined by [Elena Gurevich here](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~megereli/semin_Lena11.pdf) (apparently a seminar talk), it gives the book Topology without tears as a reference. The latter book is freely and officially made [available online](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/) by the author, Sidney Morris, see Proposition 2.5.2 and Theorem 2.5.4 (p.247-249) there, the treatment is comprehensive.

Here is an attempt at a direct proof, without verifying whether it works. For each $y\in Y$ let $r(y)=y$ (so $r$ will end up being a retraction). If $x\in C\setminus Y$ then there is a sequence of closed intervals $I_0,I_1,...$ such that $I_0=[0,1]$, $x\in\cap_nI_n$, and for each $n$ the interval $I_{n+1}$ is that closed "third" interval of $I_n$, either the left or the right, that contains $x$ (after the open middle-third of $I_n$ has been removed).

Clearly $I_0\cap Y=Y\neq\varnothing$, and since $C\setminus Y$ is open there is an $n(x)\ge1$ such that 
$I_{n(x)-1}\cap Y\neq\varnothing$ but 
$I_{n(x)}\cap Y=\varnothing$ (use compactness, and that $\{x\}=\cap_nI_n\subseteq C\setminus Y$). 
If $I_{n(x)}$ is the "right closed third" of 
$I_{n(x)-1}$ then let $J_n(x)$ be "left closed third", and if, on the other hand, $I_{n(x)}$ is the "left closed third" of 
$I_{n(x)-1}$ then let $J_n(x)$ be "right closed third". Map all of $I_{n(x)}$ to the closest point in $Y\cap J_n(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @lookingatthemoon You are welcome, thank you for accepting it!

Answer (score 0):

In Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, p. 7-8 there is a very elegant argument based on pruned trees that represent closed sets in countable products. Look at that, it's good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for every metrizable and separable space $X$ are equivalent, $X$ is zero dimensional and every nonempty closed set is a retract of $X$. I only know the proof with trees prunes and the universal Baire space by zero dimensional metrizable and separable.